# how to make my json file dynamic for some values in that?

Tags: python, json, function, loops, dictionary

i have one json file which has this path:

```
data[strSubModel][strChannel][strVdiv]['AdRawCheck']['response']['run']['1']['status']
```

and i want `['1']` dynamic so that i can add more status like:

```
data[strSubModel][strChannel][strVdiv]['AdRawCheck']['response']['run']['2']['status']
data[strSubModel][strChannel][strVdiv]['AdRawCheck']['response']['run']['3']['status']
```

i hve tried function but it didnt work for me.

Comment: Please show actual Python code that you're having trouble with

Comment: Do you just want to be able to use a variable rather than `"1"`?

Comment: You're already using variables as keys (strSubModel, strChannel & strVdiv) so you clearly know how to do that. So why can't you use some other variable for '1', '2' etc.?

Answer (score 0):

as the comments have already pointed out, it appears as though you are already using variables (in the first three branches. So you can just extend this to the one you want.

I have shown the code for clarity.

So the generic code would simply be this:

```py
# a large json file
data = {
    ... : ...,
    ... : ...
}

# variables already used
strSubModel = 'something'
strChannel = 'another thing'
strVdiv = 'a third thing'

# set the additional bit you want to be a variable
bit_i_want = '1'

# put it into the path where needed
result = data[strSubModel][strChannel][strVdiv]['AdRawCheck']['response']['run'][bit_i_want]['status']
```